# SQLAlchemy custom sorting algorithms when using SQL indexes

Tags: python, sql, indexing, sqlalchemy, collation

Is it possible to write custom collation functions with indexes in SQLAlchemy? SQLite for example allows specifying the sorting function at a C level as [`sqlite3_create_collation()`](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

An implementation of some of the Unicode collation algorithm has been provided by James Tauber [here](http://jtauber.com/blog/2006/01/27/python_unicode_collation_algorithm/), which for example sorts all the "a"'s close together whether they have accents on them or not.

Other examples of why this might be useful is for different alphabet orders (languages other than English) and sorting numeric values (sorting `10` after `9` rather than codepoint order.)

Is this possible in SQLAlchemy? If not, is it supported by the `pysqlite3` or `MySQLdb` modules, or for any other SQL database modules supported by python for that matter?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example demonstrating unicode collation algorithm for sqlite:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from pyuca import Collator

metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String, nullable=False)

collator = Collator('allkeys.txt')

def collate_unicode(value1, value2):
    return cmp(collator.sort_key(value1), collator.sort_key(value2))

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
engine.raw_connection().create_collation('unicode', collate_unicode)
metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(engine)()

for word in [u"ĉambr", u"ĉar", u"car'", u"carin'", u"ĉe", u"ĉef'",
             u"centjar'", u"centr'", u"cerb'", u"cert'", u"ĉes'", u"ceter'"]:
    item = Item(value=word)
    session.add(item)
    session.commit()

for item in session.query(Item).order_by(collate(Item.value, 'unicode')):
    print item.value
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified Denis Otkidach's answer a little bit so I'll add my changes as community wiki in case anyone else is interested:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import types
from pyuca import Collator

class MyUnicode(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.Unicode
    def get_col_spec(self):
        # Return a new Unicode type sorted with 
        # the `mycollation` function
        return 'Unicode COLLATE mycollation'

# Create the collator (sorting) function/instance
collator = Collator('allkeys.txt')
def mycollation(value1, value2):
    if False:
        # Use pyuca for sorting
        return cmp(collator.sort_key(value1), 
                   collator.sort_key(value2))
    else:
        # Normalize to lowercased combining characters for sorting
        import unicodedata
        return cmp(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', unicode(value1)).lower(),
                   unicodedata.normalize('NFD', unicode(value2)).lower())

# Create a new metadata/base/table
metadata = MetaData()
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CollatedTable'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # (Note the `unique=True` in the next line so that an index 
    #  is created, therefore stored in collated order for faster SELECTs)
    value = Column(MyUnicode(), nullable=False, unique=True)

# Create a new database connection
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
engine.echo = True # Print the SQL
engine.raw_connection().create_collation('mycollation', mycollation)
metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(engine)()

# Add some test data
for word in [u"ĉambr", u"ĉar", u"car'", u"carin'", u"ĉe", u"ĉef'",
             u"centjar'", u"centr'", u"cerb'", u"cert'", u"ĉes'", u"ceter'",

             u"zimble", u'bumble', 
             u'apple', u'ápple', u'ãpple',
             u'đjango', u'django']:
    item = Item(value=word)
    session.add(item)
session.commit()

for item in session.query(Item).order_by(Item.value): # collate(Item.value, 'mycollation')
    print item.value
```